# check if input equals a specific string without repeating code

Tags: python, input

So im making a simple console menu for my program.

```
# Example menu program
menu = """
OPTIONS
1. Option 1
2. Option 2
"""

while True:
    uinput = input(menu)

    if uinput == "quit": # repetitive code
        break
    elif uinput == "1":
        uinput = input("Input parameters: ")
        if uinput == "quit": # repetitive code
            break
        process_params(uinput, option=1)
    elif uinput == "2:
        uinput = input("Input parameters: ")
        if uinput == "quit": # repetitive code
            break
        process_params(uinput, option=2)
```

Whenever the user types `quit` into any one of those inputs, the loop breaks.

The problem is my program contains a lot of `input` functions, and I don't want to check if `uinput == "quit"` every time have an `input` function. Is there a way to do this? I thought of making a custom input function that checks the input every time, but you can't call break from another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to break out of a loop (or do anything else **exception**al that breaks the normal control flow) from an inner function call without threading a bunch of returns and checks back through multiple scopes is to raise an `Exception`.

```
class QuitException(Exception):
    pass


def get_input(msg: str) -> str:
   uinput = input(msg)
   if uinput == "quit":
       raise QuitException()
   return uinput


while True:
    try:
        option = get_input(menu)
        if option in {"1", "2"}:
            process_params(
                get_input("Input parameters: "), 
                option=int(option)
            )
    except QuitException:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure, but is this what it's supposed to do?

```
menu = """
OPTIONS
1. Option 1
2. Option 2
"""

while True:

    print(menu)
    uinput = input("Input parameters: ")

    if uinput == "quit": # repetitive code
        break

    if uinput == "1" or uinput == "2":
        process_params(uinput, option=int(uinput))
```

Comment: if `uinput` is `"1"` you probable don't want `option` to be `2`.

Comment: Can you show me or link me to a place that explains process_params?

Comment: I don't know what `process_params` is — it's just the OP's example shows them passing `option = 1` when `uinput` is 1.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear post. What I meant is that there are inputs after you select an option. Whenever the user types quit into any one of those inputs, the loop breaks

Comment: process_params is just a placeholder. I want each option to receive different parameters and do different stuff with them.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very good question and you almost have the right answer - *yes* to a dedicated custom input function. Then, the only missing puzzle piece is using exceptions as flow control!

I couldn't find a nice documentation link quickly but I found a good post about it [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/351110).

Python is built with using exceptions as a tool to control your code flow in mind. They perform faster than if statements (unless they occur frequently which isn't our case) and let's you write with very few if statements. It might seem unnatural, at first, but it is Pythonic.

The idea is to raise an exception in `custom_input` for special cases such as "quit". You maintain the logic of when the program should exit (such as "quit", "exit" or others if you need) in one place and *indicate* to the calling stack (other functions chain) that a special case needs to be handled by `raise`-ing an exception.

```py
def custom_input(prompt):
    value = input(prompt)
    if value == 'quit':
        raise KeyboardInterrupt("User requested to exit.")
    else:
        return value

def main():
    try:
        while True:
            value = custom_input(prompt = "Input parameters")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Thank you, come again! Bye!")
```

And you can use `custom_input` several times, only needing if statements for menu choices. But, having the quit logic in one place rather than repeating the code.

Couldn't post from my phone fast enough :(

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully this helps. I'm a little unsure what you are requesting.

```
User_Input = ""

while User_Input != 'quit':
    User_Input = input('Get Some Input')
```

Comment: uhh no.. When the user inputs `quit` in the middle of the loop, the loop will continue running until the end, and only until a new iteration starts then it checks `uinput == "quit"` and breaks the loop.